# setupController is not working for hasMany data

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

here is my code. when a user has only 1 property code is working fine but in case of multiple properties. setupController and aftercontroller is not working

```
 model: ->
    return @get('session.currentUser.properties')

 setupController: (controller, model)->
     controller.set('properties', model)
```

user model is

```
Userr = DS.Model.extend(
  email: DS.attr('string')
  telephone: DS.attr('string')
  properties: DS.hasMany('property', { async: true })
)

`export default User`
```

Comment: Can you create a ember-twiddle to demonstrate the problem? What is happening and what do you expect to happen? What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

it cause your property is not loaded ( async=true ) when it comes to setting up. so it will not be available. what i did was i directly findRecord with reload:true to load all the related data for that property and using the then closure i set assigned the properties.

```
var self= this;
   this.store.findRecord("user",this.model.get('id'),{reload:true}).then(function(result){
      self.controller.set('properties', result)
    }  );
```